# Curly brackets don't show.

Tags: brackets

I'm typing in LaTeX on a Linux machine (Ubuntu) using Emacs (for typing and compiling). If I type (in mathematical environment)

```
\left\{blah blah\right\}
```

I don't see any brackets at all.

If I type

```
\{ blah blah \}
```

the brackets are not scaled.

How can I fix this?

Edit

It must have been mistype or something, now everything works...

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Why did you add the backslash? Maybe this caused his problem.

Comment: @Thorsten: The backslash was there already in the code, just not shown. I simply added white lines so the code blocks are formatted right. The edit diff doesn't show that correctly. You need to view the source code to see it.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Oh, I didn't know that. I need to keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @Yotam Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: @Thorsten: Thanks for trying to help around here, but that comment should be added only after quite some time (2 days or so in my opinion), but not after 6 hours. Normally it is a good thing to wait a day before accepting an answer, so that other have the chance to give an (maybe even better) answer.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Thank you for your remark. I added the comment because Yotam edited the question to say that everything works now. But I will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @Thorsten: Ok, I didn't saw that edit. However, in this case it's actually "too localized".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try using them like this:

```
$\left\{\right\}$
```

You have to use them in mathmode and put a backslash in front of the bracket.

Answer (score 6):

when you compile the following example you will get the error

```
Missing $ inserted \left
```

The example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\left\{blah blah \right\}
\end{document}
```

You see the error is clear.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\left\{\mbox{blah blah}\right\}$ %without amsmath

$\left\{\text{blah blah}\right\}$ %with amsmath
\end{document}
```

Please create a minimal example. It is easier for use.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\{ $\floor{\frac{3}{3}}$ + $\floor{\frac{3}{3}}$ + $3$ \} + 
\{$\floor{\frac{3}{3}}$ + $3$ + $0$ \} = $9$. % example with amsmath

\end{document}
```